# ansible include_tasks ignoring tags

Tags: ansible

I have been desperately trying selectively include tasks from a collection. According to the documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-module, tags can be passed along when including tasks, in two possible ways:

1. Using the free-form

```
    - name: <whatever>
      include_tasks: tasks.yml
      args:
        apply:
          tags:
            - t1
```

2. As a parameter

```
    - name: <whatever>
      include_tasks: 
        file: tasks.yml
        apply:
          tags:
            - t1
```

Based on the above, I prepared a small proof of concept, as presented below. The idea is to have a (play)book `book.yml` use tags to pick specific tasks from a catalogue `tasks.yml`.
Unfortunately, invoking

```
ansible-playbook book.yml
```

will execute all the tasks every time `tasks.yml` is included, regardless of specifying the tags.

I have tried using Python 2.7 and Ansible 2.7, 2.8 and 2.9 on Mac OSX (Mojave).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**Code**

1. File `book.yml`

```
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      vars:
        _task_file: tasks.yml
    
      tasks:
      - name: include_tasks "{{ _task_file }}" (free-form) with tag(s) pwd
        include_tasks: "{{ _task_file }}"
        args:
          apply:
            tags:
              - pwd
        tags:
          - pwd
    
      - name: include_tasks "{{ _task_file }}" with tag(s) dummy
        include_tasks:
          file: "{{ _task_file }}"
          apply:
            tags:
              - dummy
        tags:
          - dummy
    ...
```

2. File `tasks.yml`

```
    ---
    
    - name: dummy
      command: echo -n
      tags: dummy
    
    - name: printenv
      command: bash -c "printenv | sort | grep -i ansible"
      register: _printenv
      tags: printenv
    
    - debug: var=_printenv.stdout_lines
      tags: debug
    
    - name: pwd
      command: pwd
      register: _pwd
      tags: pwd
    
    - debug: var=_pwd.stdout_lines
      tags: debug
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"The idea is to ... use tags to pick specific tasks from a catalog tasks.yml."***

A: It's not possible to use tags "inside" a playbook this way. [*`apply: tags`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#parameter-apply) will **add** the tags to the tasks **not select** them. The tags can select the tasks from "outside" of the playbook only:

- on the command line. Options: *--tags*, *--skip-tags*
- in the configuration section tags. Keys: *run*, *skip*
- in the environment. Variables: *ANSIBLE_RUN_TAGS*, *ANSIBLE_SKIP_TAGS*

See:

- [TAGS_RUN](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#tags-run)
- [TAGS_SKIP](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#tags-skip)

The next option to consolidate tags is the concept of [Ansible runner's project](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#env-cmdline).